# Isiah 34:14 - Significance of Lillith reference

Tags: isaiah, rabbinic-interpretation

As the Hebrew and Greek versions lay out:

> Her nobles shall be no more, nor shall kings be proclaimed there; all
> her princes are gone. (13) Her castles shall be overgrown with thorns,
> her fortresses with thistles and briers. She shall become an abode for
> jackals and a haunt for ostriches. (14) Wildcats shall meet with
> desert beasts, satyrs shall call to one another; There shall the
> Lilith repose, and find for herself a place to rest.

Considering the depiction of Lillith, it's hard to not mistake her for anything but a demonic entity.

### Question

Was Adam aware that he was fornicating with a demon for those handful of centuries or should we interpret it as more of an ex-ante demonic metamorphosis at the juncture of not submitting to Adam?

Comment: The idea that Adam had sex with Lilith is a midrashic tale not found in scripture, and questions about the interpretation of midrashim are out of scope here.  Please change your question to something to do with the verse in Isaiah or you may want to ask on judaism se.

Comment: https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-texts-are-open-for-examination

Comment: You're basing your Q upon a talmudic Midrash which nobody believes, without even mentioning the source or ref. Common man won't even understand the Q on lilith and I checked to find that English versions doesn't have lilith but only ISV has it, it's a night vampire kinda figure. The tale is definitely not depicting historical facts. If he had sex with demon he definitely knew it. He couldn't have an excuse that he didn't know it. I hope this answers your que. I don't know about

Comment: Lilith is a fascinating character that has intrigued Christian writers. Here is short article on C.S. Lewis' view of female villains with Lilith like features: https://www.cslewis.org/journal/nothing-yet-in-its-true-form-shifting-portrayals-of-female-villains-in-c-s-lewis-chronicles-of-narnia/view-all/

Comment: Or maybe it is also a good question to ask over at the Christianity stack exchange site? That being said, I don't understand why midrash interpretations are not allowed on this site for discussion purposes. It seems rather provincial to restrict the discussion on this site to simple form or grammatical historical criticism. Exploring the trajectory of Biblical interpretations based upon possible oral traditions connected with certain textual understandings seems like a legitimate application of hermeneutical approaches.

Comment: I do not even understand the basis of the question - Lilith is never mentioned in the Bible as associated with Adam.  Either quote a Bible passage about your question or delete the question.

Comment: Jess there's no rule that disallow the approach but the Q is vague empty, and low quality.

Answer (score 2):

Most English Bible versions translate the Hebrew word "lilith" as "screech owl", "night creature", "night bird", "night monster", or "nocturnal animals".

This item:

- starts with a quotation from Isaiah using a specific translation that personifies and leaves in the original form the word "lilith".
- immediately jumps, without explanation, to what appears to be a totally unrelated question about Adam.

The first highly biases the question, and the second relies on unreferenced mythology.

This site is supposed to ask questions about the translation of biblical verses.
But this question asks a "truth" question about obscure doctrine.

The question *might* be suitable for Christianity.SE, but even there, it would be more likely to be answered if it included references and explicit statements of its unmentioned assumptions.

Comment: Ray, the unreferenced mythology in the question was referenced in my post. It can be found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith. 
The (biased) thoughts/question about Lilith is a fascinating area to explore. Would it be more appropriate in the Christianty SE or History SE sites? Perhaps so, but I shared my thoughts, because it is fascinating to me.

Answer (score 1):

The N.E.T. notes for Isaiah 34:14 point out:

> The precise meaning of לִּילִית (lilit) is unclear, though in this
> context the word certainly refers to some type of wild animal or bird.
> The word appears to be related to לַיְלָה (laylah, “night”). Some
> interpret it as the name of a female night demon, on the basis of an
> apparent Akkadian cognate used as the name of a demon. Later Jewish
> legends also identified Lilith as a demon. Cf. NRSV “Lilith.”

For a Jewish and Christian exegetical discussion on Lilith in Isaiah 34 see [here](http://jewishchristianlit.com/Topics/Lilith/isaiah_dsc.html).

The big hermeneutical question is whether appealing to Jewish or Christian oral traditions can help discover an author's intent in what they write. Historical judgments are often made in reference to the meaning of texts based upon archeological explorations. So, why can't oral traditions of textual meanings function in the same manner?

Having said the above, my understanding of Lilith references in Jewish and/or Christian tradition is that they are rather late in transmission. So, they likely do not reflect a plausible oral tradition from the days of the composition of Isaiah 34, let alone the Genesis creation account.

The pseudepigraphical 8th–10th centuries [Alphabet of Ben Sira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith) is considered to be the oldest form of the story of Lilith as Adam's first wife. The text has a comment from Lilith to Adam, "We are equal to each other inasmuch as we were both created from the earth."

It is interesting to contrast the medieval story of Lilith, in regards to how Martin Luther once lamented about the egalitarian role of men and women that was lost due to the curse of the fall:

> Now there is also added to those sorrows of gestation and birth that
> Eve has been placed under the power of her husband, she who previously
> was very free and, as the sharer of all the gifts of God, was in no
> respect inferior to her husband. … If Eve had persisted in the truth,
> she would not only not have been subjected to the rule of her husband,
> but she herself would also have been a partner in the rule which is
> now entirely the concern of males. (Martin Luther, Lectures on
> Genesis)

For further research, see Megan Sauter's recent write up in the *Biblical Archaeology.org's* article, [Lilith in the Bible and Mythology](https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/biblical-topics/hebrew-bible/lilith-in-the-bible-and-mythology/). Also, C.S. Lewis worked with concept of Lilith in his Chronicles of Narnia series. See [here](https://www.cslewis.org/journal/nothing-yet-in-its-true-form-shifting-portrayals-of-female-villains-in-c-s-lewis-chronicles-of-narnia/view-all/).